# Is the vapour like gas produced from ice a water vapour?

Tags: thermodynamics, water

We know that a ice is a condensed form of water but when it is kept on a tray, we can see vapour like gas produced from the surface. Is that the water vapour or not?

*If it is then why mass of water remains same?*

I am a bit confused :-(

Comment: Its the water vapor condensing out of the air due to being too cold to hold its old humidity levels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If it is then why mass of water remains same?

The total mass remains the same, but it's now made up of both the gaseous and solid forms of water. The vapour you see reduces the mass of the ice, but only very slightly, so it's very hard to measure the difference.

A frost-free freezer illustrates this very well. In frost-free freezers, the cabinet is kept cold by circulating cold, dry air through it. That air carries away any vapour from the ice. The vapour is released outside the freezer, so that water is lost from the inside.

If you put some uncovered ice in such a freezer, you will see that, over weeks or months, the ice gradually disappears. If you were able to collect the water vapour that is released outside, you'd see it carries away all the mass that's lost inside.

Comment: Okay Thanks for the answer! You are better then my most teachers. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I like that compliment!